# Create HTML report like NUnit report using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, html, nunit

I have a `NUnit` project which creates xml reports at the end of `NUnit` test.

I want to create a custom report with additional links example i want to give links to some project specific files locations.

How to create such a custom report within `C#` project? Do I need to use `ASP.net` in it or is there any other method?

Comment: Question is not clear, and also what have you tried?

Comment: I m trying to create html report within c# project. One option i tried is to add asp. Net project but i am not familiar with Asp. Net

Comment: Please state explicitly what the issue is. What is stopping you from creating the custom report ? Is there any error messages ?

Comment: @Raj I am not clear how to create such a custom report within c# project. Do I need to use ASP .net in it or is there any other method

Answer (score 1):

Use Report Unit. Following link has examples using NUnit and other tools

http://relevantcodes.com/reportunit-report-generator/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.